# Question about how the ExecuteSQLRecord processor work

Tags: apache-nifi

I created a flow where I am pulling 100s K records from a DB.

- The flow cycles and pulls in batches of 15k records at a time
- The 15k records are processed and sent to Solr
- This continues until all records have been processed

The question is with the use of that processor does the connection close and reopen?

It takes longer than I want it to run and am looking to see if there is something I can do to speed up the calls on this processor.

Can someone please tell me if there is something I can do to speed this up?

I cannot just load all of the data as the server runs many flows and with what I've done I've ensured that I'm not pulling and posting more than 5mg at a time. A full pull will crush the server and cause *OutOfMemoryExceptions*.

e.g. I'm running it now and there are 102 queries that need to be ran it is only on 90 at the moment and it has been running for 45 minutes

Comment: I cant tell you for sure how ExecuteSQLRecord work but you can try something else if you have the proper column : https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.12.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.GenerateTableFetch/

Comment: processors's Scheduling -> Concurrent Tasks property determines multithreading .  if you don't see any potential concurrency issue,  can you increase this number for processing  processors after fetching data